# Boto3 DynamoDB Query Conditions not working (except for eq)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using boto3 to create a simple DynamoDB query as follows:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('course-lesson-id-part').eq(1)
)
```

This query works and return the single item just like it should.

course-lesson-id-part is my primary partition key and is numeric; I have two items in my table:

```
course-lesson-id-part: 1
course-lesson-id-part: 2
```

Ideally, [and according to this reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#dynamodb-conditions), I should be able to use the following to query all items with course-lesson-id-part > 0:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('course-lesson-id-part').gt(0)
)
```

None of the other DB Query conditions seem to be working other than .eq, which does me no good here.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Only `eq` is supported for partition keys.

> You must specify the partition key name and value as an equality condition.

Source: [Working with Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)

Comment: Right. You can only specify one partition key (i.e., equality condition), and a contiguous range of (aptly called) range keys - i.e., a <, >, <=, <=, =, between or begins_with conditions. If you want to more sophisticated filtering, then this is no longer a KeyConditionExpression, but is possible as a slow filter (FilterExpression) - on a single partition (Query operation) or the entire database (Scan operation).